# Add a property to an object returned by a function?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is a way to get all properties of 'myFields' assigned in a single statement ?

This works:

```
function fieldMap(namesString) {
    var result = {};
    var names = namesString.split(' ');
    for (index in names) {
        var name = names[index];
        result[name] = name + '/text()';
    }
    return result;
}
var myFields = fieldMap('title rating author url');
myFields['cover']="@cover";
```

This doesn't work:

```
var myFields = fieldMap('title rating author url')['cover']='@cover';
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to assign the same value to all properties of an object in a single statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change all properties of an object in a single statement, you have to write yourself a mapping method:

```
function fieldMap(namesString) { // Mike Lin's version
    var result = {};
    var names = namesString.split(' ');
    for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        var name = names[i];
        result[name] = name + '/text()';
    }
    return result;
}

Object.prototype.map = function(callbackOrValue){
    /* better create an object yourself and set its prototype instead! */
    var res = {};
    for(var x in this){
        if(typeof this[x] === "function")
            res[x] = this[x];
        if(typeof callbackOrValue === "function") 
            res[x] = callbackOrValue.call(this[x]);
        else
            res[x] = callbackOrValue;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Then you can use

```
var myFields = fieldMap('title rating author url').map(function(){return '@cover'};
    /* ... or ... */
var myFields = fieldMap('title rating author url').('@cover');
```

However, if you want to set `myFields` and change the value in the same step, try this:

```
var myFields;
(myFields = fieldMap('title rating author url'))['cover']='@cover';
```